# Do Hazelcast near-caches purge stale preloaded items?

Tags: hazelcast

We intend to use Hazelcast as data distribution layer to end user monitoring UI's for transaction processing system. The system gets accumulates records for a week and gets recycled over the weekend, clearing all state.

As there may be hundreds of thousands items, joined in a graph structure, we would like to use take advantage of the near-cache with preloading from file (i.e. if the user stops the GUI during the day and starts it later).

My question is about a case when the GUI picks up a preloaded file from a previous session. Will Hazelcast be smart enough to invalidate and purge the client entries with keys that are no longer in the cluster?

Could you provide a link to the documentation if this behaviour is documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented on the [Near Cache Preloader](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Performance/Near_Cache/Near_Cache_Preloader.html) page, the preloader only uses the file to identify the hot set. In other words it always loads the values from the cluster.

Sometimes it pays to check the manual instead of mucking with examples :-)